# PayPal IPN POST results in 0 PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm struggling with a simple storage script that should be called via PayPal IPN to save the current payment.

I'm using

```
$input = json_encode($request->all());

$paylog = Paylog::create([
   'data' => $input,
]);
```

and the result from any incoming POST is always "0".

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean to access `$_POST`

IPN messages should be verified with a postback to ipnpb.paypal.com *before* doing anything with their contents

---

IPN is a very old and clunky technology, why are you using it?

To obtain details on a 'current' payment, you should be using an API like v2/checkout/orders to facilitate the checkout. For this you need two routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

The best approval flow to pair with your two routes is https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: No it's the $request Object, and it should contain everything necessary. I'm using Laravel... Yes, Im also verifying the payment - don't worry about that. I just like to use the simple notification method, and store what's in the post - but I can't. I will not try to save the json error... Maybe this will illuminate the problem...

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
//Make sure encode values to UTF8
$input = json_encode(array_map('utf8_encode',$request->all()));

//And store
$paylog = Paylog::create([
   'data' => $input,
]);
```

**Or to make things a little more efficient:**

```
$paylog = Paylog::create([
   'data' => $json_encode(array_map('utf8_encode',$request->all())),
]);
```